# Topographical or relief data in Map APIs

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, topography

I was wondering if anyone knew of any map APIs that offer topographical or relief data?  I've had a quick look at Google and Bing APIs, but could find nothing there.

Google allow you to view a map as TERRAIN, which means you can see the topography of a map, but I want to be able to get at that data - i.e. if I were to draw a line between 2 points on Google Maps, I want to know how high above see level points along that line are.

Is this possible with any map APIs out there?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [simple example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_profile.htm) of height along a route.

I use USGS to obtain the elevation data, Google Maps API to plot the route and Google Charts to draw the elevation profile.

Full details in the associated [tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/altitude.htm).

Comment: This simple example no longer works, making it a dead answer. If there is the possibility of putting the code in the post itself, that would at least keep this answer potentially useful for future visitors. (Although of course the google elevation API is no longer free, so even with working code, this might not be a workable solution anymore for anyone without deep pockets)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few web services that provide elevation data:

- [USGS Elevation Query Web Service](http://gisdata.usgs.net/XMLWebServices/TNM_Elevation_Service.php)
- [EarthTools](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#height)
- [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#srtm3)

Also, [this site](http://www.nearby.org.uk/elevation-kml.php) can search each of them

Comment: Thanks for this.  This has helped answer my question.  If I could mark 2 answers as correct I would.  It was just that Mike had what I wanted spot on. Sorry!

Comment: @Sniffer - Hey, no apologies necessary!  Glad you found what you needed.